# VBA: track new equity (name) in a transaction statement

Tags: vba, distinct, record

We have an investment account, with mainly equities. We can download transaction history in xlsx format.

The table format looks like this

> Date       Activity        Symbols/description        Price
>
> 10/29      Buy             FLY/leasing LTD            13.92
>
> 10/22      Sell            BRFRF/BURFORD cap           1.99
>
> 10/20      Buy             BRFRF/BURFORD cap           1.92
>
> 10/17      NameChg        JGWPT/JGWPT Holding
>
> 10/13      Buy             JGW/JG Wentworth           5.31

Now, I am going to write a VBA module to

1. generate a list in a separate tab (worksheet)  to keep the UNIQUE Symbols -- the names of equities in my portfolio.
2. Only work for the 'buy' or 'sell' transactions, all other activities should be ignored
3. Any time the transaction history is updated, the code can check for any new symbols (I don't care whether it is fully automatic, or click button), and add to the list.

I am sure I can do it with a lot conditional statements and loops, but I believe there must be some better ways.

Any idea would be helpful. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Split Symbols/Description on the "/" Text to Columns. Make sure you preserve the price.

Use Microsoft Query on the Excel file in question to pull the relevant information into a table in the second sheet.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The '/' is not an issue, it's ok to take them both in the list. However, we are going to manually assign internal ID to each of the symbols in the next column in the list. The query result might be in different order if there are new equities.

Comment: Ok, so we're going to have to revise your question. What is the final layout of data before you run the query? Please revise the question to include the additional requirement (manual ID)